Sketch on an Argand diagram Re((1+i)z)=1
Sketch on an Argand diagram Re((1+i)z)=1
Could you go about this by expanding and then converting into cartesian?
Re((1+i)(x+yi))=1
Re(x+yi+xi-y)=1
x-y=1
So is it just the line y=x+1 on the complex plane?

Welcome to MSE, please use MathJax.
Your approach is correct.
